# Dynamic linking gets cleared when inserting new records

Tags: x++, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have one form in AX 2012 from which i am calling another child form which shows records that are related to the selected record in Parent form(Dynamic linking).

Now, when I am trying to create a new record in a child form, the dynamic linking between this form and its parent form gets cleared and child form starts showing all data according to its datasource and not any filtered records which I don't want.

I want to know that, how to get stick with that dynamic linking while creating new Record in a child form.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your grids really belongs to the correct datasources. If not, strange things happen.